Implement numpy's take function in xtensor
I'm trying to implements numpy's take function using the xtensor library.
The function has the following requirements:

Given data tensor of rank r >= 1, and indices tensor of rank q, gather entries of the axis dimension of data (by default outer-most one as axis=0) indexed by indices, and concatenates them in an output tensor of rank q + (r - 1).

Example with axis = 0.
Let k = indices[i_{0}, ..., i_{q-1}] then output[i_{0}, ..., i_{q-1}, j_{0}, ..., j_{r-2}] = input[k , j_{0}, ..., j_{r-2}]
data = [
    [1.0, 1.2],
    [2.3, 3.4],
    [4.5, 5.7],
]
indices = [
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
]
output = [
    [
        [1.0, 1.2],
        [2.3, 3.4],
    ],
    [
        [2.3, 3.4],
        [4.5, 5.7],
    ],
]

Example with axis = 1.
Let k = indices[i_{0}, ..., i_{q-1}] then output[j_{0}, i_{0}, ..., i_{q-1}, j_{1}, ..., j_{r-2}] = input[j_{0}, k, j_{1}, ..., j_{r-2}]
data = [
    [1.0, 1.2, 1.9],
    [2.3, 3.4, 3.9],
    [4.5, 5.7, 5.9],
]
indices = [
    [0, 2],
]
axis = 1,
output = [
        [[1.0, 1.9]],
        [[2.3, 3.9]],
        [[4.5, 5.9]],
]

I'm not totally sure how I can manipulate the xt::xarray such that I can achieve the same behaviour.
With this cycle I think I'm capturing the right subarrays and putting them in the views vector, but how do I combine them together, also accounting for the previous axis (in this case none because axis = 0)?
  const int axis = 0;
  xt::xarray<int> data = {{1, 12}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
  xt::xarray<int> indices = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}};

  std::vector<decltype(xt::strided_view(data, {}))> views;
  for (const auto &index : indices) {
    xt::xstrided_slice_vector slices{};
    for (int i = 0; i < axis; ++i) {
      slices.emplace_back(xt::all());
    }
    slices.emplace_back(index);
    slices.emplace_back(xt::ellipsis());

    views.push_back(xt::strided_view(data, slices));
  }

I have tried using the xt::tuple, but it seems it does not play nice with dynamic data structures such as vectors.
Maybe a xt::stack(xt::xtuple(...), axis) at the end could work, but I'm not sure how to make it compile.
EDIT
After messing around a bit, I think I found a possible solution that seem to be working fine on all the examples I had to run.
I'm not claiming it is the most efficient one or 100% correct, so use it with extreme caution.
If anyone has any suggestion or improvements to share, feel free to do so or post a proper answer.
Otherwise, after a while I may just self answer with this solution.
template <class T>
xt::xarray<T> take(const xt::xarray<T>& arr, const xt::xarray<int>& indexes, int axis) {
  // TODO: make sure the implementation is correct
  std::vector<std::int64_t> new_shape{};
  new_shape.insert(new_shape.end(), arr.shape().begin(), arr.shape().begin() + axis);
  new_shape.insert(new_shape.end(), indexes.shape().begin(), indexes.shape().end());
  new_shape.insert(new_shape.end(), arr.shape().begin() + axis + 1, arr.shape().end());
  xt::xarray<T> new_values = xt::zeros<T>(new_shape);

  int counter = 0;
  for (const int index : indexes) {
    xt::xstrided_slice_vector data_slices{};
    xt::xstrided_slice_vector new_arr_slices{};
    for (int i = 0; i < axis; ++i) {
      data_slices.emplace_back(xt::all());
      new_arr_slices.emplace_back(xt::all());
    }
    for (size_t i = 1; i < indexes.dimension(); ++i) {
      new_arr_slices.emplace_back(0);
    }
    data_slices.emplace_back(index);
    new_arr_slices.emplace_back(counter++);
    data_slices.emplace_back(xt::ellipsis());
    new_arr_slices.emplace_back(xt::ellipsis());

    auto data_slice = xt::strided_view(arr, data_slices);
    auto new_slice = xt::strided_view(new_values, new_arr_slices);
    for (size_t j = 0; j < data_slice.size(); ++j) {
      new_slice(j) = data_slice(j);
    }
  }

  return new_values;
}


what's this xt:: namespace? That's not standard C++.  How much C++ do you actually know?  And which version of C++ can you use? C++23 has std::mdspan which would be helpful for you. Anyway converting python to C++, don't do it line by line. Understand both languages, understand the algorithm and reimplement in C++

I'm using the xtensor library, as stated in the first line of the question. That's where the xt:: namespace is from.
The std::mspan seems interesting, but that's not what I need right now
